# TCPDF not working in cakephp 2.3.6

Tags: cakephp, tcpdf

Hi i am trying to use the TCPDF manual given in cakephp.

http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/kalileo/2010/06/08/creating-pdf-files-with-cakephp-and-tcpdf

But its not at all working in my system. I followed the exact steps there...

Error:-

```
 Class 'XTCPDF' not found
```

But there is a class name XTCPDF in my Vendor folder....
Any help plz ??
Thanks

Comment: It's offtopic, but TCPDF is really oldschool. WHy don't you use whhtmltopdf - it generate pretty much WYSIWYG pdf and the only thing is to create a pdf layout for your views. This of course could be used if you can upload the executable of the lib on your hosting and call it. http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you try change:

```
App::import('Vendor','xtcpdf');
```

to

```
App::import('Vendor','tcpdf/xtcpdf');
```

or maybe following this tutorial:
http://www.pedroventura.com/cakephp/crear-archivos-pdf-con-cakephp/

summary:

file: app/vendors/tcpdf/xtcpdf.php

```
<?php

    App::import('Vendor','tcpdf/tcpdf');

    class XTCPDF  extends TCPDF
    {

        var $xheadertext  = 'PDF creado using CakePHP y TCPDF';
        var $xheadercolor = array(0,0,200);
        var $xfootertext  = 'Copyright © %d XXXXXXXXXXX. All rights reserved.';
        var $xfooterfont  = PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN ;
        var $xfooterfontsize = 8 ;

        function Header()
        {

            list($r, $b, $g) = $this->xheadercolor;
            $this->setY(10);
            $this->SetFillColor($r, $b, $g);
            $this->SetTextColor(0 , 0, 0);
            $this->Cell(0,20, '', 0,1,'C', 1);
            $this->Text(15,26,$this->xheadertext );
        }

        function Footer()
        {
            $year = date('Y');
            $footertext = sprintf($this->xfootertext, $year);
            $this->SetY(-20);
            $this->SetTextColor(0, 0, 0);
            $this->SetFont($this->xfooterfont,'',$this->xfooterfontsize);
            $this->Cell(0,8, $footertext,'T',1,'C');
        }
    }

?>
```

file: app/views/layouts/pdf.ctp

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
echo $content_for_layout;
?>
```

action in controller:

```
function descargar($id = null)
{
    if (!$id)
    {
        $this->Session->setFlash('no has seleccionado ningun pdf.');
        $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
    }
    Configure::write('debug',0);
    $resultado = $this->MiControlador->findById($id); // info from database
    $this->set("datos_pdf",$resultado);               // info to view (pdf)
    $this->layout = 'pdf';
    $this->render();
}
```

and 
file: app/views/mi_aplicacion/descargar.ctp

```
<?php
App::import('Vendor','tcpdf/xtcpdf'); 
$tcpdf = new XTCPDF();
$textfont = 'freesans';

$tcpdf->SetAuthor("");
$tcpdf->SetAutoPageBreak( false );
$tcpdf->setHeaderFont(array($textfont,'',10));
$tcpdf->xheadercolor = array(255,255,255);
$tcpdf->xheadertext = 'Fecha: '. date('d-m-Y',time());
$tcpdf->xfootertext = 'www.example.cl';

$tcpdf->AddPage();
$tcpdf->SetTextColor(0, 0, 0);
$tcpdf->SetFont($textfont,'B',10);
$tcpdf->Cell(10,20,'Nombre:', 0, 0);

// more info

echo $tcpdf->Output('mi_archivo.pdf', 'D'); //D or I
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/app.html#loading-vendor-files Here you will find, how do you load vendor in CakePHP 2.3.6...

Comment: posting links is not answering. links may become broken in the future.